# having trouble fetching json into a fragment

Tags: android

Im having trouble fetching json data into a fragment and i need help. I dont know where im going wrong.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.crime_fragment,container);
        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerCrime);
        //gives the context of the parent activity
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
        rv.setAdapter(new OtherAdapter(this.getActivity(),fetchJSon()));
        MySingleton.getInstance(this.getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        return v;
    }

    private ArrayList<ListItem> fetchJSon() {

       final ArrayList<ListItem> items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
       stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlData, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                try {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                    for(int i = 0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ListItem listItem = new ListItem(jsonObject.getString("name"),jsonObject.getString("createdBy"),jsonObject.getString("imageUrl"));

                        items.add(listItem);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        return items;

    }
```

Comment: post your log???

Comment: what is the problem? what is your trouble?

Comment: the app is crashing if i run it

Answer (score 2):

StringRequest send an async request which means the response come back a few seconds later to the main thread. But in the meantime main thread reads the other code blocks.

So you must send the request first. You can fill the list when the response come successfully.

```
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.crime_fragment, container);
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerCrime);
     //gives the context of the parent activity 

    fetchJSon(rv);

    return v;

    }

    private void fetchJSon(final RecyclerView rv) {

        final ArrayList < ListItem > items = new ArrayList < ListItem > ();
        stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlData, new Response.Listener < String > () {@
            Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ListItem listItem = new ListItem(jsonObject.getString("name"), jsonObject.getString("createdBy"), jsonObject.getString("imageUrl"));
                        items.add(listItem);
                    }

                    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));
                    rv.setAdapter(new OtherAdapter(this.getActivity(),items));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {@
            Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}
        });

        MySingleton.getInstance(this.getContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }
```

Comment: the app is launching and exiting by itself

Comment: Can you share logcat's log about it @danny